# regex match between characters

Tags: regex, splunk

the strings are like

```
/fruit] 

/animal/lion

/plant/flower/rose
```

and i want to get only first word without slash and blacket which means fruit, animal, plant.

I did until `[^\/]*[a-z] *`
but i have no idea what is next step. can somebody help me?

Thanks

Comment: Java or Python?

Comment: Java, Python, or Splunk?

Comment: @warren actually Splunk

Answer (score 1):

In Splunk, this should do it.

```
... | rex field=foo "(?<word>\w+)" | ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String before = "...";
String after = before.replaceAll("[/](\w+).*", "$1");
```

And you can use "after".

(Java solution)